# sklearn RandomizedSearchCV with Pipelined KerasClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, pipeline

I am performing a hyperparameter tuning optimization tasks with sklearn on a Keras models. I am trying to optimize KerasClassifiers within a Pipeline...
Code follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold,RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

my_seed=7

dataframe = pd.read_csv("z:/sonar.all-data.txt", header=None)

dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input and output variables
X = dataset[:,:60].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,60]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y_encoded=encoder.fit_transform(Y)
myScaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = myScaler.fit_transform(X)

def create_keras_model(hidden=60):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=hidden, input_dim=60, kernel_initializer="normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1,  kernel_initializer="normal", activation="sigmoid"))
    #compile model
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

def create_pipeline(hidden=60):
    steps = []
    steps.append(('scaler', StandardScaler()))
    steps.append(('dl', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_keras_model,hidden=hidden, verbose=0)))
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
    return pipeline

my_neurons = [15, 30, 60]
my_epochs= [50, 100, 150]
my_batch_size = [5,10]
my_param_grid = dict(hidden=my_neurons, epochs=my_epochs, batch_size=my_batch_size)

model2Tune = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_keras_model, verbose=0)
model2Tune2 = create_pipeline()

griglia = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model2Tune, param_distributions = my_param_grid, n_iter=8 )
griglia.fit(X_scaled, Y_encoded) #this works

griglia2 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=create_pipeline, param_distributions = my_param_grid, n_iter=8 )
griglia2.fit(X, Y_encoded) #this does not
```

We see that `RandomizedSearchCV` works with griglia, whilst it does not work with griglia2, returning

> "TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit'
>   method,  was passed".

Is it possible to amend the code to make it run under a Pipeline object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `estimator` parameter wants an object, not a pointer. Try changing to `griglia2 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=create_pipeline(), param_distributions = my_param_grid, n_iter=8 )`

Comment: @VivekKumar, thanks for the initial insight. I still got a (new) error message, now "ValueError: Invalid parameter batch_size for estimator Pipeline. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimator parameter wants an object, not a pointer. Currently you are passing a pointer to method which generates the pipeline object. Try adding `()` to it to solve this:

`griglia2 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=create_pipeline(), param_distributions = my_param_grid, n_iter=8 )`

Now for the second comment about the invalid parameters error. You need to append the name you defined when creating the pipeline to the actual parameters, so that they can be passed successfully.

Look at the description at the of [Pipeline usage here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#usage).

Use this:

```
my_param_grid = dict(dl__hidden=my_neurons, dl__epochs=my_epochs,
                     dl__batch_size=my_batch_size)
```

Notice the `dl__` (with two underscores). This is useful when you want to tune the parameters of multiple objects inside the pipeline.

For example, lets say along with the above parameters, you want to also tune or specify the parameters of StandardScaler.

Then your parameter grid becomes:

```
my_param_grid = dict(dl__hidden=my_neurons, dl__epochs=my_epochs,
                     dl__batch_size=my_batch_size,
                     scaler__with_mean=False)
```

Hope this clears things.